# OleDB connection throws exception in Windows Server 2012R

Tags: c#, xls, oledbconnection

I am using a function in order to open an .xls file with multiple worksheets and copy the entire content into a .csv file.
Everything works just fine on my local machine: no exceptions, no errors etc.

But when I am running it on windows server 2012R I am getting an exception when the connection is opened.

Here is the code where I am trying to open an OleDB connection and then query through the file:

```
static void ConvertExcelToCsv(string excelFilePath, string csvOutputFile, int worksheetNumber)
    {
        // connection string

        var cnnStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excelFilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=no;Format=xls\"");

        var cnn = new OleDbConnection(cnnStr);

        // get schema, then data
        var dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            var schemaTable = cnn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            if (schemaTable.Rows.Count < worksheetNumber) throw new ArgumentException("The worksheet number provided cannot be found in the spreadsheet");

            string worksheet = schemaTable.Rows[worksheetNumber - 1]["table_name"].ToString().Replace("'", "");
            string sql = String.Format("select * from [{0}]", worksheet);
            var da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cnn);
            da.Fill(dt);
```

....

The excelFilePath is my source excel file (.xls) and csvOutputFile is the file were the content is going to be passed to.

Does anyone has any ideas why I am getting this exception??

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Well basically this is a job which is running on a server and whenever there is a fail...I am getting an error report back but it is not detailed, therefore I am only received that the function has thrown an exception and since it is failing quite fast, I am assuming that it happens when it is trying to open the connection.

Comment: I have added some code to create a file with the exception when it's failing and I will come back with an update if I get anything useful.

Comment: Without knowing more details this is a guess, but from experience it seems likely that it's because the server does not have ACE version 12.0. Try installing https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 to the server or failing that try changing the version number of the ACE connection...or even try using a JET connection.

Comment: I will do that and return with an answer. Thank you

Comment: Most probably it's either a driver issue or 32bit, 64 bit issue. You have to log exception to track it.

Comment: this is what I am getting:   System.InvalidOperationException: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbServicesWrapper.GetDataSource(OleDbConnectionString constr, DataSourceWrapper& datasrcWrapper)

Comment: I have already installed the Access Database Engine 2010 and it is still failing

Comment: If your app is a 64 bit app (or AnyCPU without 32bit preferred) then you need to install the 64bit version of ACE, with x86 you need to install the 32bit version

Comment: My windows server is on 32 bit and I think, as well as the ACE ...but I think the app is a 64 bit....I will take a look into that. Thank you!